Here i am not able to access the tree in native rust. It shows symbol name is longer than 16 bytes
Here in processor in instruction pre_sale i want to use Tree struct from whitelist. but this error comes Error: ELF error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file: Section or symbol name .bss._ZN3ico12in is longer than 16 bytes. This error comes whenever i tires to declare global variable. I have also tried to use lazy_static.
Update :-
This is my elf file line where i am getting error,
.dynamic .bss._ZN3ico12instructions9whitelist14WHITELIST_TREE17hd158279cb8bbdda1E
Processor :-
use solana_program::program_error::ProgramError;

use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    solana_program::{account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint::ProgramResult, pubkey::Pubkey},
};

use crate::instructions::{
    self, 
    create::{create_token, CreateTokenArgs}, 
    mint::{mint_token, MintSplArgs}, 
    presale::{pre_sale, BuyerArgs, PreSaleArgs}, 
    transfer::{transfer_tokens, TransferTokensArgs}, 
    whitelist::{whitelist_account, WhitelistArgs, WHITELIST_TREE}
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
enum MyInstruction {
    Create(CreateTokenArgs),
    MintSpl(MintSplArgs),
    TransferTokens(TransferTokensArgs),
    WhiteListAccount(WhitelistArgs, String),
    PreSale(),
}

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    
    let instruction = MyInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)?;

    match instruction {
        MyInstruction::Create(args) => create_token(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::MintSpl(args) => mint_token(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::TransferTokens(args) => transfer_tokens(accounts, args),
        MyInstruction::WhiteListAccount(args, admin_account) => {
            match whitelist_account(args, admin_account) {
                Ok(_) => Ok(()), 
                Err(err) => Err(err), 
            }
        }
        MyInstruction::PreSale() => {
            let tree = unsafe { WHITELIST_TREE.as_ref().unwrap() }; 
            pre_sale(accounts, tree )
        }   
    }
}

WhiteList :-
use {
    borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize},
    merkletreers::{tree::MerkleTree, utils::hash_it},
    solana_program::{entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, program_error::ProgramError},
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct WhitelistArgs {
    pub accounts: Vec<String>,
}

pub struct Tree {
    pub merkle_tree: MerkleTree,
}

pub(crate) static mut WHITELIST_TREE: Option<Tree> = None;

pub fn whitelist_account(args: WhitelistArgs) -> ProgramResult {

    let leaves: Vec<[u8; 32]> = args
        .accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|account_str| {
            let account_bytes = account_str.as_bytes();
            let mut buffer = [0u8; 32];
            hash_it(account_bytes, &mut buffer);
            buffer
        })
        .collect();

    let whitelist_tree = MerkleTree::new(leaves);

    let tree = Tree {
        merkle_tree: whitelist_tree,
    };

    msg!("Accounts have been added to the whitelist");
    msg!("{:?}", tree.merkle_tree.root);

    unsafe {
        WHITELIST_TREE = Some(tree);
    }

    Ok(())
}


Does this answer your question? Error: ELF error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file: Section or symbol name `.bss._ZN3ico12in` is longer than `16` bytes
